# How to redirect ALL the traffic from port 80 to a debugging proxy in Linux?

Tags: linux, curl, proxy

I'm working in a server side piece of code that makes a call to a RESTful API between the user request and response.

When you are debugging Node.js, PHP or any kind of server side programming that won't use the system proxy by default, I've seen myself writing in the source code that you want to go through the proxy. You can do this in your cUrl calls, for example.

In other situations I've used a transparent proxy to redirect the traffic from the port 80 to the port where the proxy is listening in the same machine.

Both solutions are far too complicated to be turn on and off without a heavy maintenance.

How to do this painless?

Comment: You could use `iptables`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use iptables to redirect port 80 traffic to your proxy port, you can configure you own transparent proxy too with squid with iptable if you want on linux.Check this link http://www.broexperts.com/2013/03/squid-as-transparent-proxy-on-centos-6-4/

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker